# Open Graph metatags - "Missing Properties" and "Inferred Property" [Facebook Share using Django]

Tags: html, django, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I am trying to create a Facebook Share button to share a page with a custom topic, description, and image. But according to: developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing (please forgive me the format, I cannot post more than 2 links) I have some problems with missing and inferred properties.

[Sharing Debugger Warnings - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWQ0d.png)

First and last metatag are loaded as raw metatags. I wonder why tags in between aren't?

[Sharing Debugger All Raw Tags - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCBQy.png)

**base.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- My og metatags -->
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{ myId }" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="{ myUrl }" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="{ myTitle }" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="{ myDescription }" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{% static 'accounts/img/share_image.png' %}" />

        <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview">
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body %}
            <h1>Base</h1>
        {% endblock %}

        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**template.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="fb-share-button"
        data-href="{ myPageToShare }"
        data-layout="button_count">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your server has to return the OG meta tags for the individual URL directly when it is requested; the Facebook scraper does not care for any client-side JavaScript (which is what turbolinks effectively use.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I am not sure I fully understand. Does it mean that Facebook scraper cannot read this script? What can I do to solve this problem? Is there any way?

Comment: You need server-side rendering of your OG meta data.

Comment: @CBroe That was it! Thanks a lot for your help!