# Why next/head content not visible in result?

Tags: next.js

I have this page: https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/zer-jewel-rez-gyertyatarto

I use next/head as docs says:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>{props.buyTicketData?.name}</title>
      <meta
        property="og:title"
        content={props.buyTicketData?.name}
        key="title"
      />
      <meta
        property="og:url"
        content={`https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/${productId}`}
        key="url"
      />
      <meta
        property="og:image"
        content="http://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/InstructionsPic5.png"
        key="img"
      />
      <meta
        property="og:image:secure_url"
        content="https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/InstructionsPic5.png"
        key="img"
      />
      <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="1251" />
      <meta property="og:image:height" content="1665" />
    </Head>
```

In DOM viewer I can see the OpenGraph content, but not in the raw HTML. Why?

It is rendered with `getStaticProps`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this post can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889871/open-graph-metatags-missing-properties-and-inferred-property-facebook-sha) or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858052/10797718) talking about `property="og:image:secure_url"`

Comment: @BenSouchet, I put thise extra elements all in the header, but still not operational, strange

Comment: @BenSouchet here challange follows :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550059/how-to-pass-argument-to-layout-component-in-next-js